# Calculating regularization parameter and feature robustness with sklearn

Tags: python, parameters, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-detection

I am working with 2-class dataset has far more number of attributes(10000~50000) than instances(100~1000), so I think feature selection is an important issue.

So I am trying to use Randomized Logistic Regression, which is known as nice solution for reducing features.

However, because of large number of features, the influence of regularization parameter, C, seems to be very large. I usually calculated the optimal C by grid search with 10-fold cross-validation using like below, but as described in [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_diabetes.html), it does not give the reliable value.

```
clist = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 100)
params = {'C' : clist}
logi = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced", penalty='l1')
grid = GridSearchCV(logi, params, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Most of time, the selected C was too large or too small, so classification(by SVM) with selected features also did not show better result than using default C 1.0.

Is there any better way for choosing regularization parameter?

The other question is the calculation of feature robustness. There are some popular method for calculate stability such as Kuncheva's index, but it seems not to be implemented in sklearn. What I can imagine is only a simple one - make n resampled dataset, select features and calculate the number of overlapping features.

Is there any recommended way for testing feature robustness?

Comment: One tip, use logspace instead of linspace.

Comment: Thank you again for your advice this time. But even the features selected from C=0.1 and C=0.2 were quite different, so I tried to use linespace instead of logspace.

Comment: @ToBeSpecific I think that's the point of using logspace. The spacing will be smaller between small values of C, and larger between large values. Anyway, if your problem has too high CV variance, maybe using the boostrap632 can help.

Comment: @toasted_flakes Thank you for advice. Although it doesn't seem to be an optimal value, but better value than 1.0 was acquired by using logspace. I am not sure it is proper to use bootstraping for finding C for randomized logistic regression which also use bootstrap, but I would like to try that.